# Inherited an ASPX site and cannot change a variable

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll, code-behind

I just inherited an ASPX site from a new customer of mine. I know ASP but I cannot figure this one out. There are two pages that seemingly do exactly the same thing (cause they should) they both read an XML file and pull in the correct child datasets 2010 for the 2010 data and 2011. I need to add a new set for their 2012 line.

I figured I could dupe one of these pages and change the "2011" to "2012." The problem is I cannot find the "2011" ANYWHERE! the only difference between the two files is:

There isn't a "year2011.aspx.cs" to be found via FTP that I can see and changing the 2011 to 2012 just throws an error. Reading up a little on the CodeBehind tag there pointed me to a few DLLs that ARE there BUT I have no idea how to edit them to make them work. Their old developer did not leave anything but what was on the server.

Any ideas on what I can do to make this work?

Comment: Can you show us your XML & explain in more details

Comment: You need to find the source code. Clearly this is an Web Application Project. Otherwise use a decompiler or ILSpy to see the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the code is compiled so there wont be any *.cs files. If you haven't got the source code as you have mentioned you will need to decompile the DLL's to allow you make any necessary edits.

Take a look at http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx , it will allow to decompile the dll back to *.cs files to allow you to make any edits.

Once you have the source code you should be able to debug and provide more information about the error you are experiencing